# How to add multiple URL to Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in SharePoint 2013 web.config

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api, cors

To resolve the CORS issue I have added the following headers in the web.config file of SharePoint 2013

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4200" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type,Accept,X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED,crossDomain,credentials,X-RequestDigest " />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
```

After this I am able to execute the SharePoint REST Api AJAX calls from the cross domain. But now I want to add another URL to the header

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4200" />
```

I cannot put * in the value as I am also allowing the credentials. Is there any way that I can add one more URL to this header.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: were you able to achieve post action in cross(edge browser), if so can you share example.

Comment: i believe it should work on edge as well. I have only tested it in chrome. if it is not working in edge can you post the issue as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got it working using URL Rewrite.

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
        <rewrite>            
            <outboundRules>
                <clear />                
                <rule name="AddCrossDomainHeader">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access_Control_Allow_Origin" pattern=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{HTTP_ORIGIN}" pattern="(http(s)?://((.+\.)?domain1\.com|(.+\.)?domain2\.com|(.+\.)?domain3\.com))" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{C:0}" />
                </rule>           
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
```

From this method we can add multiple cross domain URL's in our web.config

Original answer thread.  [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323350/access-control-allow-origin-with-multiple-domains)

Answer (score 0):

You could set Access-Control-Allow-Origin dynamically in Global.asax.

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint"%>
<%@ Application Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPHttpApplication" %>

<script runat="server">
     void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {       
                  Response.Headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", Request.UrlReferrer.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority));

                  Response.Headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials");
                  Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

                  Response.Headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Methods");
                  Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
     }
</script>
```

Check [the thread here](http://sharepointblogbyshri.blogspot.com/2017/04/access-control-allow-origin-saviour-for.html).